# C++ in-class initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, in-class-initialization

When using in-class initializers, why can I use the copy form of initialization '=' and the braced list form of initialization '{}' but no direct form '()'.

```
class foo{
    int a = 5;
    int b{5};
    int c(5);
};
```

Error: expected a type specifier

Error: syntax error: 'constant'

Comment: Because that's how the language is specified.

Comment: Read about _most vexing parse_  !!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that won't be parsed as variable but it'll be parsed as a declaration of function .That's why it doesn't let u write 5 there .As it is expecting no argument or normal or default type of argument there . And as error also suggests that it is expecting a type specified like int or anything for 5 .And another error suggests that you can not direct pass constant there in the function . It is a syntax error .

Comment: It is better not to write answer for duplicate question because it is already answer here on SO !!!

Comment: I'll keep that in mind from next time .